# Android/Kotlin retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2, okhttp

I'm just beginning with `Retrofit` and I got this error when I'm just trying to make a simple `POST request`

> retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media
>   Type

I don't know at all where is the mistake.
I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/RxJava/android-rxjava-networking-with-retrofit-gson-notes-app/) to implement `Retrofit` and `RxJava`.

There is my `RetrofitClient` implementing my `OkHttpClient`:

```
object RetrofitClient {

    private const val CONNECTION_TIMEOUT: Long = 60
    private val BASE_URL = "https://pictalio-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/"

    private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null


    fun getClient(token: String): Retrofit {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .client(getOkHttpClient(token))
                    .build()
        }
        return retrofit!!
    }

    private fun getOkHttpClient(token: String): OkHttpClient {
        val okClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        okClientBuilder.addInterceptor { chain ->
            val original = chain.request()

            val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", token)

            val request = requestBuilder.build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }
        httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC
        okClientBuilder.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
        okClientBuilder.connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        okClientBuilder.readTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        okClientBuilder.writeTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        return okClientBuilder.build()
    }
}
```

There is my `ApiService`:

```
interface ApiService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("account/login")
    fun getUserLogin(
            @Field("email") email: String,
            @Field("password") password: String
    ): Single<User>
}
```

There is how I call and treat my request's return:

```
class SignInActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener, RequestSignIn.sendDataResponse, RequestGetUser.sendDataResponse {

    private var user: User? = null
    private var pDialog: SweetAlertDialog? = null
    lateinit var emailEditText: EditText
    lateinit var passwordEditText: EditText
    var persistentUser: PersistentUser? = null
    //Initialization of disposable
    private val disposable = CompositeDisposable()

    private lateinit var apiService: ApiService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.signin_activity)

        emailEditText = findViewById(R.id.email)
        passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.password)
        //Initialization of apiService
        apiService = RetrofitClient.getClient("").create(ApiService::class.java)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        val email: EditText
        val password: EditText

        email = findViewById(R.id.email)
        password = findViewById(R.id.password)
            R.id.login -> {
                if (Tools.isValidEmail(email.text.toString())) {
          disposable.add(apiService.getUserLogin(email.text.toString(), password.text.toString())
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe({ user ->
                                pDialog!!.dismissWithAnimation()
                                Log.e("USER", "token: " + user.token)

                            }, Throwable::printStackTrace)
                    )
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@SignInActivity, getString(R.string.enter_valid_email), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    //emailnotvalid
                }
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        disposable.dispose()
    }
}
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

**EDIT :**
I have removed `@FormUrlEncoded` and add `.header("Content-Type", "application/json")`
and I'm sending now a `JSONObject` as `Body` as follows :

```
disposable.add(apiService.getUserLogin(JSONObject(map)))
```

But I have a `400 BAD REQUEST` from my server.
I even added `ScalarsConverter` to my `RetrofitClient`.

```
.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
```

So I have tried with a `RequestBody` as follows

```
fun getUserLogin(@Body requestBody: String): Single<User>
disposable.add(apiService.getUserLogin(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), JSONObject(map).toString())) .
```

and it worked as well! How can I simply send a `JSONObject` instead of every time create a `RequestBody`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Status code 4xx means that there's an error in the request sent by the client; in this specific case 415 means that the Content-Type of your request is not supported by the server.

Checking the URL you provided in your code, the server is expecting an `application/json-patch+json` MIME type, but you're providing `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead (that's what the `@FormUrlEncoded` annotation is for).

To fix the issue you should change `getUserLogin` method to use the appropriate Content-Type (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35765674/2340612)) and to send the appropriate JSON payload (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027472/retrofit-sending-json), which also tells you how to set a custom header).

Comment: Thx for your answer which is working but I still have a problem if you could see my EDIT, please :)

Comment: it would be interesting to check why the first solution gives you a 400 Bad Request, but that would require debugging or at least adding an interceptor to log your request. My guess is that you may have forgotten a `@Body` annotation just before the argument in `getUserLogin` method (where you had `@Field` in your previous example), as that will tell Retrofit to use that parameter as the request body for your call. I wouldn't bet money on that, though :-)

Comment: Nop. I already have put `@Body` before my argument :) Check the new EDIT

Comment: I have debugged and I have `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8` for my body. How can I change it as `application/json` ? I already have put for my `header` but it doesn't affect the `Body`.

Comment: The reason why you get `text/plain; charset=utf-8` is that your method accepts a `String` and it gets converted to a `RequestBody` (i.e., the only thing the library understands and can send as a request payload) by the default `ScalarConverter`. That converts Strings and primitive types to text and sets that specific content type, regardless of your annotation. Solution is to either create/use a custom converter (e.g., GsonConverter) or directly create a `RequestBody` as you did. Note that converter creates a `RequestBody` anyway under the hood, so the second solution would be easier

Comment: Ok so I will keep that haha thank you for the explanation and unblocked me!